# Explanation of code for opening gallery intent in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am  a beginner in Android. Please explain the given Java code which is used to open Gallery Intent and choose image. I mean what is the purpose of the given words in the code. for ex:Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
`Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);`

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents is that whenever you want to understand something about the famework, the Android documentation should be the first place you review, it contains almost all the information for any method/constant of whatever you are trying to use from the Framework.

**setType :** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setType(java.lang.String)

**setAction :** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setAction(java.lang.String)

**startActivityForResult :** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)

**createChooser :** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender)

**ACTION_GET_CONTENT :** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT

It is as easy as just typing on Google `android + <the method you want>` :)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain it to you the easiest way possible without confusing you with technical words

.

=====THE LONG EXPLANATION=====
There are four lines of codes, we will fragment each one to have a better reading :

LINE 1) "Intent intent = new Intent();"

- Intent -> this is the type of class, you know it because it starts with an uppercase letter
- intent -> this is the name of the Intent you are creating, you know it's a variable because it starts with a lowercase letter
- =  -> at this point, you have a variable called intent of type Intent, that has nothing in it for now. Calling the = sign indicates that you will fill your variable with what follows the = sign

  - new Intent(); -> this indicates that a new class Intent is created. You know it because it has the word new in front and () after the class name, that represents the constructor of a class.

=> so basically this line indicates that you are creating a new class object of type Intent and you affect it to a variable named "intent".

.

LINE 2) "intent.setType("image/*");"

- intent.setType -> you are calling the method called "setType" of your "intent" previously created.
- ("image/*"); -> the setType method of the class Intent parameter. Here, it indicates that you want to set the type of your "intent" to be an image type.

=> this second specifies that the type of data to return will be an image

.

LINE 3) "intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);"

- intent.setAction -> you are calling the method "setAction" of your "intent" previously created.
- (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); -> You are using the static final variable of type String from the Intent class called "ACTION_GET_CONTENT". It allows you to select a particular kind of data and return it.

=> to simplify, this line specifies which action will be performed, meaning that if a user has several apps for see images, he will be able to choose which one to use

.

LINE 4) "startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);"

- startActivityForResult -> the default method called "startActivityForResult" of the class Activity.
- Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture") -> give the proper interface for the user to pick how to send data and allow you to specify a prompt indicating what they are doing
- , -> indicates the separation between parameters of a method
- SELECT_IMAGE -> this is the custom request code you pass in to identify that you want to select an image (for example : int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;)

=> put very simply, this line permit to get an access to the photo selected

.

.

=====THE SHORT EXPLANATION=====
Put all together, the block of code you showed will create an intent that allows the user to choose an image application of its choice, and get an image from it. You can then use this image in the method onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data).

I hope this will help !